# PHP Laravel Framework Routing-Blade

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm working on Laravel framework so I just making different examples to learn.I wrote this code block:

show.blade.php

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Hello,{{ $user->username }}</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

route.php

```
Route::get('users/{username}',function($username){

    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    return View::make('users.show',['user=>$user']);
});
```

I m calling my users with this url :`http://localhost:8888/l4/public/users/xxx`

Error:

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: user (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/l4/app/views/users/show.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a bug around. :)

```
Route::get('users/{username}',function($username){

    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->first();

    return View::make('users.show',['user' => $user]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`return View::make('users.show')->with('user' , $user);`